# List of packages bionic installs by default?

Tags: 18.04, package-management

Title says it all.

Background: I just upgraded from xenial to bionic using `do-release-upgrade`. It was a bit of an adventure, due to the upgrade procedure corrupting my `sources.list`. Some crucial packages were not installed, because apt was no longer aware of them. I got past that, and now have a functional system, but I'd like to know whether there's anything else I'm missing. If I could find a list of packages bionic installs by default, I could make a comparison.

Comment: If you *release-upgrade* from one release to the next, all packages installed (if available in repos) will be re-installed (with new versions), so what you end up with depends on what you had installed prior-upgrade (from official repositories).  For best results in upgrade; you should remove 3rd party, then re-install after the release-upgrade has completed. The release-upgrade process is intended for official packages only.

Comment: The `release-upgrade` process did try to disable all my other repos, but seemed to corrupt the entries for the canonical repos in the process.